# Screen active but no sockets in /var/run/screen

Tags: centos, shell, gnu-screen

I have a game server running on Centos 7 via `screen`.

I can confirm that the game server is running, I can connect to it with the client, and `ps faux` gives me this output:

```
steam    10111  0.0  0.0 127904  3028 ?        Ss   Jul09   0:00 SCREEN
steam    10112  0.0  0.0 115444  3548 pts/2    Ss   Jul09   0:00  \_ /bin/bash
steam    16558  0.0  0.0 113180  2700 pts/2    S+   Jul09   0:00      \_ /bin/bash ./avorionsrv.sh
steam    16564  4.1  5.7 2276908 944748 pts/2  Sl+  Jul09 234:32          \_ ./bin/AvorionServer --gala[...]
```

However, I can't reattach to that screen session (it was started by the "steam" user):

```
[steam@atlantis ~]$ screen -r 
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

And trying to get the list of screens yields "no sockets found"

```
[steam@atlantis ~]$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-steam.
```

The same happens with the root user, and a `find` in the screen socket directory tells me that there is nothing there.

```
┌─(/root)──────────────────────────────────────────────────(ROOT@atlantis:pts/0)─┐
└─(11:54:05)──> find /var/run/screen                             <──(Fri 13 Jul)─┘
/var/run/screen
/var/run/screen/S-root
/var/run/screen/S-steam
```

Any ideas on how to reattach to that screen?

Comment: `screens` by default are managed per user. The easiest way to reattach that screen is assuming the user steam identity.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro that was my first try, I had started screen from the "steam" user, and of course I tried reattaching to it from the same user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like your `screen` socket files got deleted out from under `screen`. You can trigger `screen` to recreate them like so by send the `SIGCHLD` signal to them using the `kill` command:

```
$ kill -CHLD 30860
$ ls /var/run/screen/S-username/
30860.pts-4.localhost
```

Where the PID, 30860, is the PID of `screen`. There are additional methods highlighted in the FAQ titled: [archived Gentoo Wiki FAQ](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/Screen#Uncommon_problems).

#### References

- [How do I reconnect to a lost screen (detached, missing socket)?](https://superuser.com/questions/58525/how-do-i-reconnect-to-a-lost-screen-detached-missing-socket)
- [archived Gentoo Wiki FAQ](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/Screen#Uncommon_problems)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!
Just a side note, how did the socket files get deleted? It's the first time that happens to me, and I've been using screen for at least ten years now, almost always with long (week/month long) processes.

Comment: @fanfurlio - terrific, glad it worked out.